# Не могу заставить работать функцию exec Python3.4

Tags: python-3.x, exec

Переписываю программу на Python2 под изменения в третьей ветки Python. В сценарии есть строка, в которой исполняется некоторый кусок кода из файла с помощью функции exec. А именно - это набор переменных языковой локализации.

Вот пример первых строчек файла russian.txt:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Файл русской языковой локализации
#
string_lang_mobile_client_label = "Мобильный клиент сайта [color=#key_text_color]"
string_lang_name_program = "HeaTDV4A:"
string_lang_plugin = "Плагины"
string_lang_articles = "Статьи"
string_lang_add_answer_in_forum = "Добавить пост"
```

Теперь при

```
exec(open("russian.txt").read()
```

получаю ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Libs/programdata.py", line 70, in <module>
    exec(open("Data/Language/russian.txt").read())
  File "<string>", line 1
    ﻿# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier
```

Подскажите, где я ошибаюсь, так как ч третьей веткой Python знаком только по наслышке?

Comment: Покажите файл russian.txt

Comment: Ну, в общем, в вопросе же я привел кусок. Кстати, решение данной проблемы такое: exec(open("russian.txt"), encoding='utf-8-sig').read())

Comment: Вы правы -- невнимательный был, подумал что это часть кода, в котором exec вызывается. Попробовал эти строчки у себя запускать проблем не было, кодировка того файла utf8?

Comment: Да, кодировка utf-8.

Comment: related: [What is an alternative to execfile in Python 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/436198/4279)

Comment: @Xyanight В коде в вопросе не хватает правой скобки (хотя действительная ошибка вызвана utf-8 BOM). [Опубликуйте ваш комментарий про utf-8-sig как ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Посмотрите, не подходит ли [`runpy.run_path('russian.txt')`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24261031/4279) больше в вашем случае.

Comment: Вариант с exec(open("russian.txt"), encoding='utf-8-sig').read()) мне кажется более логичный и читабельнее, что, естественно, решает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение данной проблемы:

```
exec(open("russian.txt"), encoding='utf-8-sig').read())
```